# How to modify sale order line when an invoice is created?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-11

I do some modification on `sale.order.line` I add some fields, one of those fields is a checkbox.
[image]

my request is when I want to create an invoice only checked line are invoiced, how can I do this Please?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is two solution for your problem either override create invoice line function or `remove sale_order_line(hide)` from sales and make new model which has same fields like `sale_order_line` add all your field there (product, realize all these fields). Gave functionality so that if checkbox is enabled(realize in your case) that automatically will added in sale order line and which checkbox is disable will remove from `sale_order_line` (You have to override create, write and unlink function of that model). By this way the lines which is enabled will be added in `sale_order_line` and everything will be done in odoo way